# Advise controller about cell selected in a sub-level

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView where a cell can have another collectionView inside, and so on.

I need to, when a button in a sub-cell (e.g., mainController - collectionView - cell - collection view - **cell**) is selected it t advise the mainController about that action, so i can perform some stuff in the mainController.

Any tips about the best approach?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSNotifications and put the necessary information into the `userInfo` dictionary.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing, though I'm debating the the trade off of convenience vs the global nature of notifications.  NSHipster did a good writeup a while back http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/

Comment: Nice writeup @Brandon Roth.. Thanks for the share

Comment: Actually, without having read the writeup, this is a proven pattern when changing / retrieving information from objects that are being recycled, such as in table or collection views. You can still ensure encapsulation by picking very specific notification names.

Comment: My initial idea was to create some king of delegation, between Childs and super objects... But this it clearly a better solution